# Start an app and set its size and position in windows

Tags: windows, scripting, position, resize

In Windows I would like to be able to run a script or application that starts an another application and sets its size and location.  An example of this would be to run an application/script that starts notepad and tells it to be 800x600 and to be in the top right corner.  Does anyone have any ideas regardless of language?

Comment: What do you mean by "sets its size and location"?

Comment: @TTG: I can't even guess what's needed here . . .

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
$ xterm -geometry 135x35+0+0
```

which puts an xterm at the top-left of the screen (`+0+0`) and makes it 135 columns by 35 lines? Most X apps take a -geometry argument with the same syntax (though often in pixels, not characters like xterm), and you can obviously put that in a shell script.

Alternatively, if the program is already running, the xwit command can be used to move it:

```
xwit -move 0 0 -columns 135 -id $WINDOWID
```

That will move the xterm its running in to the top-left corner of the screen, and make it 135 columns wide. It works on any window, not just xterms. For example:

```
xwit -move 0 0 -id 0x6600091
```

just moved my browser window. You can find window IDs with `xwininfo`, `xlsclients`, or several others.

Comment: That looks like it is for a UNIX OS (is this correct?)  I edited the question after you posted to specify the OS.  Thanks though for the quick response.

Comment: Well, its actually any X Window system setup, which usually — but not always — means a Unix variant. No idea how to do this on Windows, but hopefully this answer will be useful to someone...

Answer (score -1):

Some OSs or desktops allow to set the size and location of a window in a config dialog, for example [KDE](http://www.kde.org/).